# Missing Hard Drive Space

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

I tried to shrink my C: drive from 600GB down to 300GB and it worked fine initially. Then I booted into my other OS and shrunk its partition down as well. When I booted back into Windows Disk Management says it is still 600GB even though in the properties it says it is 300GB. I cannot shrink it again so I am effectively missing 300GB of hard drive space. Any ideas?

the other Operating system is OS X (Hackintosh). I shrunk Windows in Disk Management and OS X in Disk Utility. Here is my Disk Management screenshot.

[[image: disk management]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSWG8.png)

At the top is says C?: is ~300Gb but in the box in the middle it says it is still ~600GB. Edit: also not sure why it says all of E: is free but that might just be an issue with the Windows drivers for reading OS X partitions

Comment: My other OS? How did you 'shrink' (2x)? A disk management screen shot and/or a listing of partitions might help too.

Comment: OS X (Hackintosh). I shrunk Windows in Disk Management and OS X in Disk Utility. [Here](http://i57.tinypic.com/16jesrl.jpg) is my Disk Management screenshot. At the top is says C?: is ~300Gb but in the box in the middle it says it is still ~600GB. **Edit:** also not sure why it says all of E: is free but that might just be an issue with the Windows drivers for reading OS X partitions

Comment: I wonder if this is a conflict of information from the GPT to the MBR which still exists on GPT disks? The picture is crasy, as it makes zero sence how the 2 different type of displaying of the data show different ammounts.  There must be a clue in that.

Comment: That's why I'm so confused! Shrinking the C: drive worked fine at first, but as soon as I booted into OS X it said C: was back to 600GB. I don't know how OS X would change it though...

Comment: If you don't already have a backup, you should be making one of any data you have right now before you do anything else....

Comment: I don't have an external drive to back up to but I'm not really worries since I don't have anything on it besides downloaded programs, which I don't mind redownloading if necessary, since it is a recently built PC. I will be getting a backup drive soon though! **Edit:** and honestly at this point maybe wiping my drive and starting from scratch may be what I need haha